# How to sit the size for seaborn pairplot chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to draw an `sns.pairplot` with one value in x_axis but multiple values in y_axis

This is what I got. All the figure in one row. Does Anyone know how I can get a bigger plot? or in multiple columns?

The chart is here:

[image]

Comment: You could start by providing a [mcve] of the issue and exactly explain how the plot should look like. At the moment you have something like 50 columns which simply do not fit into the jupyter cell.

Answer (score -1):

As per the comment to your question, the reason that the plot is small, is because it does not fit into the Jupyter Notebook output cell. Try right clicking and opening in a new tab or saving it to a file.

If you want display the figure within a Notebook, you can make several calls to `sns.pairplot` with a subset of columns each time. You could also use `sns.FaceGrid` with `plt.scatter` for more granular control over what is plotted where.